# Unable to make executable that properly communicates with node.js

Tags: node.js, spawn, child-process

I'm testing the communication between node.js and executables launched as child processes. An executable will be launched from within node.js via `child_process.spawn()` and its output will be monitored by node.js. I'm testing this capability both on Linux and Windows OSs.

I've successfully spawned `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and listened to its output, but my own executables can't seem to write correctly to stdout (in whatever form it exists when captured by node.js).

Test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    long x = 1;

    while (true)
    {

        fprintf(stdout, "xtime - %ld\n", x++);
        usleep(1000000);
    }
}
```

(Note: some `include`s may be useless; I've not checked them)

Comment: Did you try adding a `fflush(stdout);` after your `fprintf()`?

Comment: @mscdex That did it! I had a nagging feeling it was something like that, but was _always_ sure it was something more complicated. If you post a proper answer, I'll happily accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdout` output is not automatically flushed (at least on *nix) when `stdout` is not a tty (even if there is a newline in the output, otherwise a newline generally flushes when `stdout` is a tty).

So you can either disable `stdout` buffering entirely via `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` or you can manually flush output via `fflush(stdout);`.